# JMS in the spring framework

Tags: java, spring

I've found that spring has its own [JMS](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html) implementation. My question is is the JMS implementation tightly coupled to the spring framework.

For instance, will it be easy to migrate from the Spring's JMS to some another [JSR-914](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=914) implementation (In case, say if we decide to use some `EJB`-container).

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#remoting-jms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring does not have its own implementation of the JMS API; it has support for JMS, so that you can use JMS "the Spring way". If you want to use messaging via JMS, you'll still need to use a product that provides an implementation of the JMS API together with Spring (for example HornetQ or ActiveMQ).

If you use Spring-specific classes such as `JmsTemplate` in your code then yes, you are tying your code to the Spring framework, and you'd need to rewrite that code in case you decide to not use Spring anymore.

Comment: So, as far as I understood I still have to have third-party jars for JMS. Could I ask you about integration ActiveMQ with the Spring Framework? Is it going to be solved just by adding a maven dependency or it's a more sophisticated operation?

Comment: @St.Antario Spring is usually good at detecting things automatically, so it's adding a Maven dependency and maybe some configuration.

Comment: Just for advice. Do yourself use one of those implementations you mentioned in the answer?

Comment: @St.Antario I've used HornetQ. But you'll have to investigate for yourself which is suitable / best for your application. There are more than the two I mentioned.